# How to manually add numbers to CappedCrowdsale

Tags: solidity, remix

How do I add number of hard cap tokens in the below code (where in code), for instance 2000 ETH. I cant add it in Create of RUn (Remix) since Crowdsale and CappedCrowdsale are separate contracts.

```
contract CappedCrowdsale is Crowdsale {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  uint256 public cap;

  function CappedCrowdsale(uint256 _cap) public {
    require(_cap > 0);
    cap = _cap;
  }


  function validPurchase() internal view returns (bool) {
    bool withinCap = weiRaised.add(msg.value) <= cap;
    return super.validPurchase() && withinCap;
  }


  function hasEnded() public view returns (bool) {
    bool capReached = weiRaised >= cap;
    return super.hasEnded() || capReached;
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The constructor takes a `_cap` parameter... are you just asking how to pass in a value to the constructor?

Comment: You just need to make sure you've referenced the Crowdsale contract correctly in your CappedCrowdSale. Then you create a CappedCrowdSale contract with the capped value and the compiler will take care of creating the inherited methods and everything else that comes with the Crowdsale contract.

Comment: I mean, where in this code to add Hard cap value?

Comment: Cappedcrowdsale does referwnce Crowdsale. If not correctly then can you show how?

Answer (score 1):

When deploying your smart-contract you have to provide _cap parameter which will be your hard cap.

in a smart-contract, the function having the same that the contract is the constructor, which is the function that is automatically called on instance creation of a class ( here class = smart-contract ).

To be able to deploy your contract you'll have to provide Crowdsale contract code source.

You can either copy-paste Crowdsale code in the same file, like this :

```
contract Crowdsale {
    ...
}

contract CappedCrowdsale is Crowdsale{
    ...
}
```

Or you can import the Crowdsale from another .sol file. If the file is in the same folder you could do :

```
import './Crowdsale.sol'

contract CappedCrowdsale is Crowdsale{
    ...
}
```

Also, note that in the partial code you gave you have the following line :
`using SafeMath for uint256;`

Which means you'll probably have to include the SafeMath smart-contract to be able to deploy your contract.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding to your question, you might need to deploy Crowdsale Contract first and then deploy CappedCrowdsale Contract with the parameter _cap to be the hard cap I'd like to set.